# Inserting a Comment in Docx file *around* a text inside a run

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, wordml

How do you search for a specific text inside a text run (in Docx using the OpenXML SDK 2.0) and once you find it how do you insert a comment surrounding the 'search text'. The 'search text' can be a sub string of an existing run. All example in the samples insert comments around the first paragraph or something simple like that... not what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to break it up into separate runs. Try using the DocumentReflector - it even genereates C# code - to look at a document created with word. The structure should look something like this (simplified):

```
<paragraph>
  <run>...</run>
  <commentRangeStart />
  <run>search text</run>
  <commentRangeEnd />
  <run>...</run>
</paragraph>
```

Answer (score 0):

For somebody who might be still looking for the answer:

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850832(v=office.15).aspx) is the code for that:

```
private void AddComment( Paragraph paragraph, string text )
        {
            string commentId = GetNextCommentId();
            Comment comment = new Comment() { Id= commentId, Date = DateTime.Now };
            Paragraph commentPara = new Paragraph( new Run( new Text( GetCommentsString( text ) ) ) { RunProperties = new RunProperties( new RunStyle() { Val = "CommentReference" } ) } );
            commentPara.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties( new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "CommentText" } );
            comment.AppendChild( commentPara );
            _comments.AppendChild( comment );//Comments object
            _comments.Save();

            paragraph.InsertBefore( new CommentRangeStart() { Id = commentId }, paragraph.GetFirstChild<Run>() );
            var commentEnd = paragraph.InsertAfter( new CommentRangeEnd() { Id = commentId }, paragraph.Elements<Run>().Last() );
            paragraph.InsertAfter( new Run( new CommentReference() { Id = commentId } ), commentEnd );
        }
```